# Getting Transaction Failed Error: No valid responses from any peer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

The error I got:
    `enrollSTudent Transaction Failed: text error trying invoke business 
    network.Error: No valid responses from any peers.
    Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: transaction returned 
    with failure: ReferenceError: NS is not defined.`
I also got an other error saying there is a memory leak but fixed it. However, i cant fix NS_ is undefined error. Here is the code i used below:

Chaincode.js

```js
Chaincode.js

    use strict;
    /**
    * Write your transction processor functions here
    */
    var NS_UNIVERSITY   = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.university';
    var NS_COLLEGE      = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.college';
    var NS_STUDENT      = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.student';

    /**
     * create a new certificate entry
    * @param {org.gryphon.casestudy.university.issueCertificate} args - student 
    details
     * @transaction
     */
    function issueCertificate(args) {
    var certificateId = 'CertificateID-' + Date.now().toString();
    var certificate;
    var _assetRegistry;
    return getAssetRegistry(NS_UNIVERSITY + '.Certificate')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            var factory = getFactory();

            certificate = factory.newResource(NS_UNIVERSITY, 'Certificate', 
    certificateId);
            certificate.issuedTo = args.studentName;
            certificate.programName = args.programName;
            certificate.issuedDate = new Date();
            certificate.certificateId = certificateId;
            return assetRegistry.add(certificate)
                .then(function (_res) {
                    return getParticipantRegistry(NS_STUDENT + '.Student');
                })
                .then(function (assetRegistry) {
                    _assetRegistry = assetRegistry;
                    return assetRegistry.get(args.studentID)
                    .then(function (certifiedStudent) {
                        certifiedStudent.certificateId = certificateId;

                    var event = factory.newEvent(NS_UNIVERSITY, 
    'certificateIssuedEvent');            
                    event.certificateId = certificateId;
                    emit(event);                                

                        return _assetRegistry.update(certifiedStudent)    
                    })
                .then(function (_res) {
                    return (_res);
                }).catch(
                    function (error) {
                            return (error);
                    });
                });
            });
    }

    /**
    * approve affiliation of college
    * @param {org.gryphon.casestudy.university.approveAffiliation} args - id of 
    college
    * @transaction
    */
    function approveAffiliation(args) {
    var registry;
    return getParticipantRegistry(NS_COLLEGE + '.College')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            registry = assetRegistry;
            return assetRegistry.get(args.memberId)
                .then(function (college) {
                    college.isApproved = 1;
                    return registry.update(college)
                        .then(function (_res) {
                            return (_res);
                        }).catch(
                            function (error) {
                                return (error);
                            })
                });
        });
     }


    /**
    * Enroll Program to the college
    * @param {org.gryphon.casestudy.college.enrollProgram} args - id of college
    * @transaction
    */
    function enrollProgram(args) {
    var registry;
    return getParticipantRegistry(NS_COLLEGE + '.College')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            registry = assetRegistry;
            return assetRegistry.get(args.collegeId)
                .then(function (college) {
                    if (college.isApproved == 1) {
                        college.programs.push(args.programName)
                    }
                    return registry.update(college)
                        .then(function (_res) {
                            console.log(_res)
                            return (_res);
                        }).catch(
                            function (error) {
                                return (error);
                            })
                });
        });
    }
    /**
     * Student can enroll them to a College and Program
     * @param {org.gryphon.casestudy.student.enrollStudent} args - student 
    details
     * @transaction
     */
    function enrollStudent(args) {
    return getParticipantRegistry(NS_STUDENT + '.Student')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            var factory = getFactory();
            var studentId = 'Student-' + Date.now().toString();
            var student = factory.newResource(NS_STUDENT, 'Student', studentId);
            student.name = args.name;
            student.dob = args.dob;
            student.memberId = studentId;
            student.programName = args.programName;
            student.collegeName = args.collegeName;
            return assetRegistry.add(student)
                .then(function (_res) {
                    return (_res);
                }).catch(
                    function (error) {
                        return (error);
                    });
        });
    }

    /**
    * College can request Affiliation to the University
    * @param {org.gryphon.casestudy.college.requestAffiliation} args - name of 
    college
    * @transaction
    */
    function requestAffiliation(args) {
    return getParticipantRegistry(NS_COLLEGE + '.College')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            var factory = getFactory();
            var collegeId = 'College-' + Date.now().toString();
            var college = factory.newResource(NS_COLLEGE, 'College', collegeId);
            college.name = args.name;
            college.memberId = collegeId;
            college.isApproved = 0;
            college.programs = [];
            return assetRegistry.add(college)
                .then(function (_res) {
                    return (_res);
                }).catch(
                    function (error) {
                        return (error);
                    });
        });
    }
```

events.js file:

```js
function requestAffiliation() {
    // Show Progress untill the task is complete
    document.getElementById('college_progress').innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/progress.gif"/>';

    // Get the attributes from the UI i.e College Name
    let college_name = document.getElementById('college_name').value;

    // Set the Payload for the Post restapi call
    let options = { 'college_name': college_name };
    {
        // Use Async ajax call to post a request to the Client App
        $.when($.post('/composer/client/requestAffiliation', options)).done(function (_res) {

            // End progress display
            document.getElementById('college_progress').innerHTML = '';

            // Update the UI with college list
            displayCollegeList();

            // Close the Modal Dialog
            closeModal();
        });
    }
}


/**
 * Display Colleges
 */
function displayCollegeList() {

    // Use Async ajax call to get a list of colleges from the Client App
    $.when($.get('composer/client/getCollegeList')).done(function (_res) {

        // Successful response received, lets check it on browser console
        console.log(_res.college_list);

        let _str = '';
        let _nstr = '';

        // We will now build the Table to be displayed in UI
        _str += '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>isApproved</th></tr>';
        _res.college_list.forEach(function (_row) {
            // Check is college is approved or NOT aaproved by university
            let td = (_row.is_approved == 0) ? '<td class="red"> NOT APPROVED</td>' 
                    : '<td class="green"> APPROVED</td>';

            _str += '<tr><td>' + '<a href="#" onClick=enrollProgram("' + _row.id + '")>' 
                    + _row.name + '</a></td>' + td + '</tr>';
            if (_row.is_approved == 0) {
                _nstr += '<input type="checkbox" name="collegeIds" value="' 
                    + _row.id + '">' + _row.name + '</input></br>';
            }
        })
        _str += '</table>';

        // Display College List
        document.getElementById('college_list').innerHTML = _str;
        document.getElementById('approve_list').innerHTML = _nstr;
    });
}



function submitApproveAffiliation() {
    let options = {};
    let arr = '';
    document.getElementById('approval_progress').innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/progress.gif"/>';
    $("input:checkbox[name=collegeIds]:checked").each(function () {
        let options = {};
        options.college_id = $(this).val();
        {
            $.when($.post('/composer/client/approveAffiliation', options)).done(function (_res) {
                document.getElementById('approval_progress').innerHTML = '';
                let val = _res.result;
                displayCollegeList();
                closeModal();
            });
        }
    });
}




function submitEnrollProgram() {
    document.getElementById('program_progress').innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/progress.gif"/>';
    let options = {};
    options.program_name = document.getElementById('program_name').value;
    options.college_id = collegeId;
    {
        $.when($.post('/composer/client/enrollProgram', options)).done(function (_res) {
            document.getElementById('program_progress').innerHTML = '';
            let val = _res.result;
            displayCollegeList();
            closeModal();
        });
    }
}

function submitGenerateCertificate() {
    let options = {};
    let arr = '';
    document.getElementById('certificate_progress').innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/progress.gif"/>';
    $("input:checkbox[name=gen_cer_student]:checked").each(function () {
        let options = {};
        options.student_id = $(this).val();
        {
            $.when($.post('/composer/client/issueCertificate', options)).done(function (_res) {
                document.getElementById('certificate_progress').innerHTML = '';
                let val = _res.result;
                displayStudentList();
                closeModal();
            });
        }
    });
}


function submitTakeAdmission() {
    var selected_program = $("input[name=program]:checked").val();
    if (selected_program == null) {
        alert('No Program Selected');
        return;
    }

    let student_name = document.getElementById('student_name').value;
    let student_dob = document.getElementById('student_dob').value;

    let studentDob = new Date(student_dob);
    if (studentDob == null) {
        alert('Incorrect Date Format');
        return;
    }

    let val = selected_program.split('##');
    let arr = '';
    document.getElementById('admission_progress').innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/progress.gif"/>';
    let options = {};
    options.student_name = student_name;
    options.student_dob = studentDob;
    options.college_name = val[0];
    options.program_name = val[1];
    {
        $.when($.post('/composer/client/takeAdmission', options)).done(function (_res) {
            document.getElementById('admission_progress').innerHTML = '';
            let val = _res.result;
            displayStudentList();
            closeModal();
        });
    }
}

/**
 * get History
 */
function getHistorian() {
    $.when($.get('fabric/getHistory')).done(function (_res) {
        let _str = '<h4> HyperLedger Transaction Blocks: ' + _res.result + '</h4>';
        if (_res.result === 'success') {
            _str += '<h3>Total Blocks: ' + _res.history.length + '</h3>';
            _str += '<table id="tt"><tr><th>Transaction Hash</th><th>Transaction Type</th><th>TimeStamp</th></tr>';
            _res.history.sort(function (a, b) { return (b.transactionTimestamp > a.transactionTimestamp) ? -1 : 1; });
            for (let each in _res.history) {
                (function (_idx, _arr) {
                    let _row = _arr[_idx];
                    _str += '<tr><td>' + _row.transactionId + '</td><td>' + _row.transactionType + '</td><td>' + _row.transactionTimestamp + '</td></tr>';
                })(each, _res.history);
            }
            _str += '</table>';
        }
        else { _str += formatMessage(_res.message); }
        document.getElementById('historian').innerHTML = _str;
    });
}

/**
 * Display Students
 */
function displayStudentList() {
    $.when($.get('composer/client/getStudentList')).done(function (_res) {
        console.log(_res.student_list);
        let _str = '';
        let _nstr = '';
        _str += '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Certificate ID</th></tr>';
        _res.student_list.forEach(function (_row) {
            let cid = (_row.certificateId == null) ? '...' : _row.certificateId;
            _str += '<tr><td>' + _row.name + '</td><td>' + cid + '</td></tr>';
        })
        _str += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('student_list').innerHTML = _str;
    });
}

let collegeId = null;
function enrollProgram(id) {
    collegeId = id;
    var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#' + 'enrollProgram').fadeIn($(this).data());
}

function approveAffiliation() {
    var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#' + 'approveAffiliation').fadeIn($(this).data());
}

function takeAdmission() {
    console.log('takeAdmission......');
    $.when($.get('composer/client/getCollegeList')).done(function (_res) {
        let _str = '';
        _str += '<table><tr><th>College</th><th>Programs</th></tr>';
        _res.college_list.forEach(function (_row) {
            if (_row.is_approved == 1) {
                let _pro_str = '<table>';
                _row.programs.forEach(function (_pro) {
                    _pro_str += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="program" value="' + _row.name + '##' + _pro + '">' + _pro + '</input></td></tr>';
                })
                _str += '<tr class="mark"><td>' + _row.name + '</td><td>' + _pro_str + '</table></td>' + '</tr>';
            }
        })
        _str += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('admission_list').innerHTML = _str;
    });

    var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#' + 'takeAdmission').fadeIn($(this).data());
}


function generateCertificate() {
    console.log('generateCertificate......');
    $.when($.get('composer/client/getStudentList')).done(function (_res) {
        let _str = '';
        _str += '<table><tr><th>Select</th><th>Student ID</th><th>Student Name</th></tr>';
        _res.student_list.forEach(function (_row) {
            if (_row.certificateId == null) {
                _str += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="gen_cer_student" value="' + _row.id + '"></input></td><td>' + _row.id + '</td><td>' + _row.name + '</td></tr>';
            }
        })
        _str += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('student_cer_list').innerHTML = _str;
    });

    var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#' + 'generateCertificate').fadeIn($(this).data());
}

function verifyCertificate() {
    let public_id = document.getElementById('verify_cer_id').value;
    if (public_id == '') {
        alert('Please Enter valid Public ID');
        return;
    }

    /*
        let options = { id: public_id };
        document.getElementById('verify_progress').innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/progress.gif"/>';
        $.when($.get('composer/client/getCertificateById', options)).done(function (_res) {
            console.log(res.certificates);
        });
    */

    document.getElementById('verify_progress').innerHTML = '<img src="./icons/progress.gif"/>';
    $.when($.get('composer/client/getStudentList')).done(function (_res) {
        let list = _res.student_list;
        var result = null;
        list.forEach(function (v) {
            console.log(v);
            if (v.certificateId == public_id) {
                result = v;
            }
        });
        console.log(result);

        if (result == null) {
            alert('Certificate Validation Failed - No such certificate found!');
            closeModal();
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById('_student_name_').innerHTML = result.name;
        document.getElementById('_program_name_').innerHTML = result.program;
        document.getElementById('_date_of_issue').innerHTML = Date().toString().split('2018')[0] + '2018';
        document.getElementById('__cer_id__').innerHTML = public_id;

        document.getElementById('verify_progress').innerHTML = '';
        closeModal();
        displayCertificate();
    });
}

function displayCertificate() {
    var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#' + 'certificate').fadeIn($(this).data());
}
```

This is mostly the working code for my hyper ledger. As i said the error is NS_ is not defined but i clearly checked all my code and found that i never mistyped NS_

Comment: hi, please paste your model file (or files, if namespaces in separate .cto files etc). Might be (just taking issueCertificate function), though not tried your code is using an assetRegistry handle (when updating a participant registry and registry, ie with assetregistry-named resource). Also note that: new Date() etc is non-deterministic code etc etc

Answer (score 0):

this works for me (ps. should reflect the participant registry naming ('stuRegistry' rather than being an 'assetRegistry' but that still works anyway FYI) - not sure if you provided (judging by the error msg above) an invalid namespace in the transaction class?

FYI my namespaces are defined as :

```
  ...

  var NS_UNIVERSITY   = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.university';
  var NS_COLLEGE      = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.college';
  var NS_STUDENT      = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.student';

  ...
    /**
         * Student can enroll them to a College and Program
         * @param {org.gryphon.casestudy.student.enrollStudent} args - student 
        details
         * @transaction
         */
        function enrollStudent(args) {
        return getParticipantRegistry(NS_STUDENT + '.Student')
            .then(function (stuRegistry) {
                var factory = getFactory();
                var studentId = 'Student-'  +   +  Date.parse(args.timestamp);  // removed this non deterministic code:  Date.now().toString();
                var student = factory.newResource(NS_STUDENT, 'Student', studentId);
                student.name = args.name;
                student.dob = args.dob;
                student.memberId = studentId; 
                student.programName = args.programName;
                student.collegeName = args.collegeName; 
                return stuRegistry.add(student)
                    .then(function (_res) {
                        return (_res);
                    }).catch(
                        function (error) {
                            return (error);
                        });
            });
        }
```

for issueCertificate, here's an example written with `async / await` as its easier/simpler and use the transaction (`args`) `timestamp` field to generate your id deterministically (not `new Date()`):

```
/**
    * Write your transcation processor functions here etc
    */
    var NS_UNIVERSITY   = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.university';
    var NS_COLLEGE      = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.college';
    var NS_STUDENT      = 'org.gryphon.casestudy.student';

    /**
     * create a new certificate entry
    * @param {org.gryphon.casestudy.university.issueCertificate} args - student details
     * @transaction
     */
   async  function issueCertificate(args) {

    // `Date.now().toString();` is non-deterministic
     var certificateId = 'CertificateID-' +  Date.parse(args.timestamp);

     var factory = getFactory();
     const  assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry(NS_UNIVERSITY +  '.Certificate');

     const  certificate = factory.newResource(NS_UNIVERSITY, 'Certificate',  certificateId);
     certificate.issuedTo = args.studentName;
     certificate.programName = args.programName;
     certificate.issuedDate = new Date();
     certificate.certificateId = certificateId;

     await assetRegistry.add(certificate) ;

     const  participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(NS_STUDENT + '.Student');

     const certifiedStudent =  await participantRegistry.get(args.studentID)

     certifiedStudent.certificateId = certificateId;

     var event = factory.newEvent(NS_UNIVERSITY,  'certificateIssuedEvent');            
     event.certificateId = certificateId;
     emit(event);  

     participantRegistry.update(certifiedStudent);
  }
```

Comment: Hey. The error iam getting is at enrollstudent() function not at issuecertificate()

Comment: Hey.  I posted comments on `enrollstudent()`